# Error when passing data to my view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website in Asp.net MVC. I currently am working on a page that will feature dropdowns that are created based upon a users statistics. To do this, I have set up a `@Html.DropDownListFor` that uses a increment system to fulfill this randomly generated system. In my Post method, I can get my dropdown values by calling `RightsFor_1`, and so on as shown below.

My problem is that when I run my program, I get the error stated below occurring on my `@Html.DropDownListFor` line of code.

Snippit of code in view:

```
     @for(int i = 0; i < Model.labPermData.Count(); i++)
        {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName)</b> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>"RightsFor_"+m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName, Model.lpdd, "Select One")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

I currently am trying access the values in the controller using this:

```
        var value1 = Request["RightsFor_0"];
        var value2 = Request["RightsFor_1"];
        var value3 = Request["RightsFor_2"];
        //... and so on
```

Error received:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: Why are you trying to perpend "RightsFor_" to the name of the control (meaning it will never bind to your model when your post)? - It should be just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName, Model.lpdd, ..)`

Comment: I guess I was attempting to use "RightFor_" so that I could access each value in the POST controller by using Request["RightsFor_0"], Request["RightsFor_1"], ETC. How could I use your method without running into problems with some values being null? Thanks

Comment: Because depending on the user, some dropdown values will be null. I.e. labPermData[2+]  won't have any values.

Comment: What has the fact that _some dropdown values will be null_ got to do with it? Never use `Request[...]` to get your values. You have a model. Bind to it and post back to it. You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You can't append strings in a lambda expression like that. Add a name attribute to the dropdown that uses your incremented name instead.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName, Model.lpdd, "Select One", new { name = "RightsFor_" + m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName })
```

Something else you may be able to do is create the string before putting it in the lambda.

```
@{ string rightsFor = "RightsFor_" + m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName; }
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>rightsFor, Model.lpdd, "Select One")
```

Comment: Adding `new { name = "RightsFor_" + m.labPermData[i].Lab.LabName }` will do nothing - it certainly wont change the `name` attribute

Comment: It gives me a new error and won't let me use the new { name = "RightsFor_" .....} method anyway. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using a foreach instead of a for loop?

this should be close

```
@foreach (var lab in Model.ToList())
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <b>@lab.LabName</b> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>"RightsFor_"+lab.LabName, Model.lpdd, "Select One")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```